# SFDC Campaigns: Updating responded checkbox, but campaign members not udpating

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

I've found several Campaigns where the Campaign Member statuses were incorrectly marked as Responded.

Take an Event campaign for example: the member statuses "No Show" and "Registered" had the Responded checkbox ticked. I've now updated these campaigns so that only the "Attended" member status has Responded checked.

However, the associated Campaign Members with a member status of "No Show" or "Registered" are still showing as Responded.

Is there a delay between updating the Campaign Statuses and Salesforce updating the corresponding Campaign Member records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Campaign statistics may be delayed by up to ten minutes. This should be in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, but it's been over 24 hrs and the campaign members haven't updated. i.e. Campaign members with a Responded or No Show status are still marked as responded.

Comment: @JamesGunn That behavior is not consistent with the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_setup.htm&type=5). Try contacting support, see what they say. I'd be curious to see if there's a system bug or just a documentation bug.

Comment: I've got it! It's a Lightning Experience issue. I've now switched back to Classic. When I update the Responded checkbox on the Campaign, Campaign Members are automatically updated.

Comment: @JamesGunn Good to know. Hopefully they'll get it fixed at some point.